# PHP, Prestashop, foreach on so many subcategories and so many products

Tags: php, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to get a list of child categories with their respective products inside them.
The code works if I have 50 products and 3 categories.
The problem is that: if I have more than 1500 products divided by 6 categories, my code returns an error page for the necessary waiting time for loading (I think).

### This is my code:

```
        $prodotti = '';
        foreach ($children as $chi){
        $prodotti .= '
        <div style="">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">
                  '.$chi[name].'
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th style="width: 80%">
                  Prodotto
               </th>
               <th align="right" style="width: 10%">
                  N. Valori
               </th>
               <th align="right" style="width: 10%">
                  Prezzo
               </th>
            </tr>';
            foreach ($products as $pro){
                if(in_array($chi[id_category],Product::getProductCategories($pro[id_product]))){
                      $prodotti .= '
                        <tr>
                           <td style="font-size: 9pt; color: #9E9F9E">
                              '.$pro[name].'
                           </td>
                           <td align="right" style="font-size: 9pt; color: #9E9F9E">
                           ...
                           </td>
                           <td align="right" style="font-size: 9pt; color: #9E9F9E">
                            '.$my_currency_iso_code.'
                            '.$pro[price].'
                           </td>
                        </tr>'; 
                }
            }
        $prodotti.='
        </table>
    </div>';   
        }
```

Thanks, greetings

Comment: Have you tried doing any profiling of this script's performance? Even with something simple like `microtime()`? Without some basic information it might be difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, when I launch the code, the whole site is blocked and after 2 minutes and 30 seconds it gives me back:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server at mail@mail.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

How could I insert and use microtime () and make it work if everything is blocked?

Comment: You can write how much time each loop run took to a log, for instance. If that in itself has a detrimental impact on performance, you can limit the total execution to 60 seconds and see how long each run takes. Speaking of which, a low `execution_time` value might be one reason you get the error.

Comment: PrestaShop comes with the smarty template engine. You should really try to use it instead of building your html in PHP. It makes the code easier to maintain and then you can also use the smarty cache for your tpl which will improve performance.

Comment: @Jeppsen
I replied below, I changed my code, but the problem is that: I have two additional foreach to get categories with the corresponding products in the .tpl file, then: two cycles in php and two more in smarty in the tpl.

instead if I build the complete HTML from php and I refer it already built to smarty I can skip two foreach with the respective controls on smarty ...

In this topic there are both two codes ... some solution?

Answer (score 0):

@Ynhockey

I had to change the code a bit.
Now the code will create an array, inside it will find products associated to categories, this array will then be sent via smarty.

I tried to use microtime (); ... but, although I have looked for guides, the operation is unknown to me.

The value returned is as follows: 0.81050395965576

This is the new code with the implementation of microtime ():

```
public function __construct($id_lista, $smarty)
{
    $this->idlista = $id_lista;
    $this->smarty = $smarty;

    $this->id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
    $idlang = $this->id_lang;
    $this->id_shop = Context::getContext()->shop->id;
    $idshop = $this->id_shop;

    /*********************************************************************/

    //Get $icpn['id_category'], $icpn['lista_name'], $icpn['id_currency']
    $icpn = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT cate_list, lista_name, id_currency FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'rec_ps_beta WHERE id_rec_ps_beta = "'.$id_lista.'"');

    //Update di listalink e lastupdate
    Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'rec_ps_beta SET listalink = "'._PS_BASE_URL_._MODULE_DIR_.'recpsbeta/lista/'.$icpn['lista_name'].'.lista", lastupdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id_rec_ps_beta = "'.$id_lista.'"');


    //VALUTA
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $currency = $context->currency;
    $id_pscurr = $currency->id;

    if($id_pscurr == $icpn['id_currency']){
        $converti = 0;
    }else{
        $converti = 1;
    }
    //segno valuta
    $setcurrency = new CurrencyCore($icpn['id_currency']);
    $sig_setcurr = $setcurrency->sign;   


    $this->cateinfo = Category::getCategoryInformations(explode(',', $icpn['cate_list']));

    $timecate_start = microtime(true);
    foreach($this->cateinfo as $cats){
            $products = Product::getProducts ($idlang, 0, 0, 'name', 'ASC', $cats['id_category'], true);

            foreach ($products as $pro){

                        if($converti == 0){ 
                            $price = $pro['price'];
                            $price = number_format($price, 2).' '.$sig_setcurr;
                        }
                        elseif($converti == 1){
                            $price = Tools::convertPrice($pro['price'],$id_setcurr);
                            $price = number_format($price, 2).' '.$sig_setcurr;
                        }

                        $products_arr[] = array ('ctid'=>$cats['id_category'],
                                        'name'=>$pro['name'],
                                        'price'=>$price
                                        );

            }           
    }
    $timecate_end = microtime(true);

    $this->$timecate_end_start = $timecate_end - $timecate_start; 
    $this->products_arr = $products_arr;
    $this->listaname = $icpn['lista_name'];       
}
```

How should I interpret the following result: 0.81050395965576  ?